# CS6 programs close after startup

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs6

I can't start my Photoshop, Illustrator or InDesign CS6 anymore, it just shuts down as soon as it's done loading, without any errors. Only Bridge CS6 will start.

I tried launching with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> but it did not work.

Then I tried uninstalling it (With all the preferences as well), and install it again, that did nothing - still the same issue.

I updated Windows and my graphics drivers (GeForce 332.21 - NVS4200M) after the issue started.

I tried both the 32bit and the 64bit version.

I have manually removed the preferences file.

I have disabled the firewall and my AV.

I have logged out and back in of the Creative Suite Utility.

My hosts file is not blocking any sites.

I am running Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit.

Comment: I've had problems with CS6 lately due to memory. If I've got other stuff running when I launch it it often decides to close itself without even asking. As it is I get warnings when it is running, and I definitely can't run it at the same time as Chrome.

Comment: I got 16 gigabytes of RAM, and I'm only using 4 right now, it seems unlikely that is the issue.

Comment: Did you update the drives before or after the issue?

Comment: After the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried contacting Adobe support, but with no luck.

I had luck by doing the following:

- Uninstalled all Adobe software (with the remove Preferences option enabled)
- Manually removed the `C:\ProgramData\Adobe`, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\SLCache` and `C:\ProgramData\regid.1986-12.com.adobe` folders.
- Ran CCleaner cleaner and registry fixes.
- Rebooted my machine
- Installed my Adobe CS6 bundle
- Launched my apps

It asked me for a serial this time, and then it asked me too provide the serial that I updated from. I updated 5.5 to 6 some time ago, and it seems that this combined with the Creative Cloud broke everything somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try manually deleting the preferences file. Under Vista or 7, look here (because un-installing and reinstalling the suite will not affect your preferences):

`Users/[Username]/AppData/Roaming/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop [version #]/Adobe Photoshop [version #] Settings`

[Source - How to delete/reset Photoshop preferences](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/375776?tstart=0)

If that fails, then the issue could be due to an entry in the registry. Try uninstalling the suite, then running a reg cleaner (such as CCleaner), and then try installing again

> If you use the [Creative Cloud Utility](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5419615#5419615#5419615) then
>
> 1. Launch Adobe Creative Cloud
> 2. Go to Preferences and then signout
> 3. Relaunch Photoshop and resignin using same Adobe ID.

Also make sure the firewall allows the connection to the Creative Cloud Utility.

Comment: I tried everything, but no luck. I can't find the Service Manager, listed under the services?

Comment: I can't find anything in the log, nor in the `Control Panel\System and Security\Action Center\Reliability Monitor` everything looks fine.

Comment: No, I don't have any log-like files in that path. As a side effect of reinstalling the entire suite, my other programs now does the same thing, where they can't open. I do have Creative Cloud installed, yes.

Comment: I tried logging out, but Photoshop did the same thing. I logged in again and now it says `Download error. Can't connect to adobe servers, 503. Firewall bla bla bla` but I'm logged in.

Comment: @AllanKimmerJensen Can you disable your firewall please and try again

Comment: Tried that and it could connect, but still no Apps starting up!

Comment: @AllanKimmerJensen Can you try again. Totally disable the firewall and AV. Then go to preferences, signout and then open Photoshop and see if you can sign in?

Comment: I tried that, it does not work. Only Bridge CS6 will start, not Photoshop, Illustrator or InDesign... they all just close.

Comment: Yes I did try that, and I also uninstalled with the `remove preferences` flag.

Comment: @AllanKimmerJensen You could check your hosts file isn't disallowing it? However, I'm sorry, I think you need to ask Adobe direct. Don't forget to post the findings if they can help.

Comment: My hostfile is empty, I checked that when I disabled my firewall. I'll contact them, thanks for now.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone is still interested.  I found a fix that worked for me.  It seemed that something had messed up within the C:\Programdata\Adobe\AdobeSL folder.
The fix was to delete the AdobeSL folder.  This would be recreated when you open a CS6 program.  Only other thing you have to do is reserialize CS6